# Haskell JSON queue

Tags: haskell

I would like some help with Haskell, I am really new to the language and to Functional Programming (have had contact with it in JavaScript, but nothing much)

I need to parse different types of JSON objects, that are defined by a parameter, and at first store them for later treatments, example:

```
[
  {
    "new_agent": {
      "id": "8ab86c18-3fae-4804-bfd9-c3d6e8f66260",
      "name": "BoJack Horseman",
      "primary_skillset": ["bills-questions"],
      "secondary_skillset": []
    }
  },
  {
    "new_job": {
      "id": "f26e890b-df8e-422e-a39c-7762aa0bac36",
      "tipo": "rewards-question",
      "urgent": false
    }
  },
  {
    "job_request": {
      "agent_id": "ed0e23ef-6c2b-430c-9b90-cd4f1ff74c88"
    }
  }
]
```

That means I need to store 3 different types of arrays, which will have to interact with each other in the future.

So far with tutorials I have found instruction enough that led me to this simple code for printing one object with fromJSON and toJSON, which I could replicate to the others, but I still don't know how to grab the object by the first parameter (new_agent, new_job, job_request), before deciding how to parse it:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, DeriveGeneric #-}
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Text
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B
import GHC.Generics
data Agent =
  Agent { agentId  :: Text
         , name   :: Text
         , primary_skillset  :: [Text]
         , secondary_skillset :: [Text]
           } deriving Show

instance FromJSON Agent where
 parseJSON (Object v) =
    Agent <$> v .: "id"
           <*> v .: "name"
           <*> v .: "primary_skillset"
           <*> v .: "secondary_skillset"
 parseJSON _ = mzero          

instance ToJSON Agent where
 toJSON (Agent agentId name primary_skillset secondary_skillset) =
    object [ "id"  .= agentId
           , "name"   .= name
           , "primary_skillset"        .= primary_skillset
           , "secondary_skillset" .= secondary_skillset
             ] 

jsonFile :: FilePath
jsonFile = "sample-input.json"  
-- Read the local copy of the JSON file.
getJSON :: IO B.ByteString
getJSON = B.readFile jsonFile   
main :: IO ()    
main = do
 -- Get JSON data and decode it
 d <- (eitherDecode <$> getJSON) :: IO (Either String [Agent])
 -- If d is Left, the JSON was malformed.
 -- In that case, we report the error.
 -- Otherwise, we perform the operation of
 -- our choice. In this case, just print it.
 case d of
  Left err -> putStrLn err
  Right ps -> print ps
```

I am looking for an answer (if possible with code snippets) to the following questions:

- how to grab the object within an object by its id and then add it to an array
- after storing the object in an array, how do I "iterate" over it whenever I need to use that one specific info again (search by object key)
- how to assign (update) the JSON inside the array, keeping it there

Comment: Define a sum type with one variant for each different object type (e.g. `data SomeObj = AnAgent Agent | AJob Job | AJobRequest JobRequest`) and define the `fromJSON` function by checking that the given `Value` is an `Object` and then checking that the hashmap for that object has exactly one field, whose key is one of the three keys for your variants, and then recursively parsing the `Value` corresponding to that key.

Comment: [Here's](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.2.3.0/docs/src/Data-Aeson-Types-FromJSON.html#line-1506) how it's done in aeson itself; the only difference will be the values matched against `key`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should get you most of the way to doing what you want to do.  It uses a similar technique to what was suggested by user2407038 .  The three different data types are collected into a sum type : `SomeObj` .  Three different parsers are created for the `SomeObj` type and the first one to succeed is the one used - the other two are not used.

When possible I let the compiler automatically define the JSON functionality.

I added additional code to verify the results by converting back to JSON and then decoding that JSON.

The "`DuplicateRecordFields`" language extension was needed so that both `Agent` and `Job` could have an `id` field.

Once the JSON is parsed you should be able to use `List` functionality to do the search and update operations that you described.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Text
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as B
import GHC.Generics

data Agent = 
    Agent { id :: Text
          , name :: Text
          , primary_skillset :: [Text]
          , secondary_skillset :: [Text]
          } deriving (Show, Generic)

instance FromJSON Agent
instance ToJSON Agent

data Job = 
    Job { id :: Text
        , tipo :: Text
        , urgent :: Bool
        } deriving (Show, Generic)

instance FromJSON Job
instance ToJSON Job

newtype JobRequest = 
    JobRequest { agent_id :: Text
               } deriving (Show, Generic)

instance FromJSON JobRequest
instance ToJSON JobRequest

data SomeObj = 
      AnAgent Agent
    | AJob Job
    | AJobRequest JobRequest
    deriving (Show, Generic)

newAgentTag = "new_agent"
newJobTag = "new_job"
jobRequestTag = "job_request"

instance FromJSON SomeObj where
  parseJSON (Object v) =
    let -- create multiple parsers.
        parseAgent = AnAgent <$> (v .: newAgentTag)
        parseJob = AJob <$> (v .: newJobTag)
        parseJobRequest = AJobRequest <$> (v .: jobRequestTag)
    in -- Use one of the collection of parsers.
        parseAgent <|> parseJob <|> parseJobRequest

  parseJSON _ = mzero

instance ToJSON SomeObj where
  toJSON (AnAgent agent) = object [newAgentTag .= agent]
  toJSON (AJob job) = object [newJobTag .= job]
  toJSON (AJobRequest jobRequest) = object [jobRequestTag .= jobRequest]

jsonFile :: FilePath
jsonFile = "sample-input.json"
-- Read the local copy of the JSON file.
getJSON :: IO B.ByteString
getJSON = B.readFile jsonFile
main :: IO ()
main = do
 -- Get JSON data and decode it
  d <- (eitherDecode <$> getJSON) :: IO (Either String [SomeObj])

  -- If d is Left, the JSON was malformed.
  -- In that case, we report the error.
  -- Otherwise, we perform the operation of
  -- our choice. In this case, just print it.
  case d of
    Left err -> putStrLn err
    Right ps -> do
      print ps

      -- convert back to JSON.
      let j2 = encode ps -- 
      print j2

      -- decode the newly converted JSON
      let d2 = eitherDecode j2 :: Either String [SomeObj]
      case d2 of
        Left err -> putStrLn err
        Right ps2 -> do
          print ps2
```

Comment: Thanks you very much! it's already helping me a lot. Although I came by a scenario, where it doesn't seem to be parsing the input if you put it in some order... I get Error in $[4]: key "job_request" not present, the weird thing is that if I place a job request instead of the present object (new_agent), it parses the object, so I imagine it is getting stuck in job_request...
Also, could you tell me exactly which object Ima put in the array? is it variable ps or variable d?

Comment: This may mean that there is something wrong with the "new_agent" object that you are parsing.  In this case, what would happen is that all three parsers ( parseAgent, parseJob, parseJobRequest) would fail.  After each of the first two failures (parseAgent, parseJob ), the code goes on to try the next parser (parseJob, parseJobRequest).  After the last failure ( parseJobRequest),  you get the 'key "job_request" not present' error.

Comment: Variable ps holds a list of SomeObj.  Variable d either holds the same list of SomeObj or an error if it was unable to parse the json.